# How do I hide referrer link in woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a link that is in the short description of a woo-commerce product. This link type is there in every product I have (different of course).

I'll need a script to automatically change the links. These are the attempts I tried so far:

1. WP-HideRefer
   I have installed the plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hiderefer/), did not work. Did not change any links.
2. Added scripts
   I used the script provided in https://anonym.to/ and put in at the end of my footer.php (before ), did not work.
3. Tried many other Wordpress hide referrer plugins, did not work.

Up until this point, I'm lost. I am not sure.

TL:DR
Appending text in front of every external link (link in short desc/normal desc of woocommerce product EXCEPT own website domain/link.

```
https://www.google.com/ is on my woocommerce product. 
When user loads the product, he sees https://anonym.to/?https://www.google.com/ instead. 
(https://anonym.to/? + link)
```

Comment: So do you want to modify/change the link, or do you want to make sure the site they end up at can't see your site as the referring site? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Wesley-Synio Im sorry. Basically append a text in front of every link. Lets say https://www.google.com/ is on my woocommerce product. When user loads the product, he sees https://anonym.to/?https://www.google.com/ instead. (https://anonym.to/? + link)

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will replace all URLs on a WooCommerce product page in both the excerpt (short description) as well as the longer description/content if you want.

It uses a regex to replace the URLs.

```
function so61548594_anonymize_urls($description) {
    $prefix = 'https://anonym.to/?';
    $description = preg_replace(
        '#(<a.*?)href=["\']([^"\']+)["\'](.*?>[^>]*</a>)#i',
        ('$1href="' . $prefix . '$2"$3'),
        $description
    );
    return $description;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'so61548594_anonymize_urls');
add_filter('the_content', function ($description) {
    if (function_exists('is_product') && is_product()) {
        return so61548594_anonymize_urls($description);
    }
    return $description;
});
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Should it be placed in footer.php or another file?

Comment: I have pasted in footer.php and it did not work. I encapsulated the code within a <?php ?> tag too

Comment: Do you have a custom theme? Then put it in functions.php there. Or otherwise you can create a new file or folder in the plugins directory and add a new file with the text of the code there. But then you also have to add the required plugin header (at least the name) to the top of the file. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/ And you have to enable the plugin in the dashboard as well.